# Vue2 - Lazy loading on route level is not working?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, lazy-loading, vue-cli

Currently, I'm testing Vue.js, and I wonder about it's out of the box lazy loading abilities. Maybe I get it wrong, but it seems not work work proper.

**What I did:**

I created a new project by Vue CLI 3 "vue create vtest", then I added 2 new components and added them to the router as async component with a webpack chunkname. Vue's in code guide from it's starter template regarding code-splitting says:

**router/index.ts**

`// this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
// which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.`

So I expect it will lazy-load when I visit one of these routes. They won't load if I do not visit them. Well, they load anyway, for example when I visit just the original Home component, which does actually not use on of my 3 separated, code-splitted routes which called About, Foo and Bar. But as you can see on my screenshot which shows all requests the Home component loads.

[image]

Here are my routes:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/foo',
    name: 'Foo',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "foo" */ '../views/Foo.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/bar',
    name: 'Bar',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "bar" */ '../views/Bar.vue'),
  },
];
```

Here is my repository, with just very few differences to the Vue CLI's starter template:

https://github.com/hellokvn/vue-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be prefetching those lazy load chunks. It is possible to turn off prefetching, if you want to test it further.

ref: [prefetching](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#prefetch)